# Maxscript function doesn't update in while loop

Tags: maxscript

I have this function in maxscript that checks if verts are in the camera frame. What I want to do is put the function in a while loop and move the camera back, and every time the camera moves it should check if the object is in camera or not. But when I do that, the function in the while loop doesn't update, it always returns the values from the first check.

```
fn getVertsInViewport theObject =
(
local theVerts = #() --return array
local theMesh = snapshotasmesh theObject --grab the mesh from top of the stack
local theCount = theMesh.numverts --get the number of vertices 
local theTM  = viewport.getTM() --get the current view's transformation
local screen_width = renderWidth --get the current render height
local screen_height = renderHeight --get the current render width
for v = 1 to theCount do --loop through all vertices
(
    local thePos = (getVert theMesh v) * theTM --transform vertex in view space
    --get the world location of the upper left corner of the camera view at the depth of the vertex
    local screen_origin = mapScreenToView [0,0] (thePos.z) [screen_width,screen_height]
    --get the bottom right corner at the vertex depth
    local end_screen = mapScreenToView [screen_width,screen_height] (thePos.z) [screen_width,screen_height]
    --calculate the world size based on the two corners
    local world_size = screen_origin-end_screen
    --calculate the X and Y aspect factors
    local x_aspect = screen_width/(abs world_size.x)
    local y_aspect = screen_height/(abs world_size.y)
    --calculate the screen coordinates using all the above data:
    local screen_coords = point2 (x_aspect*(thePos.x-screen_origin.x)) (-(y_aspect*(thePos.y-screen_origin.y)))
    --if the vertex is outside of the screen (negative or higher than the render size), collect it
    if screen_coords.x <= 0 or screen_coords.y <= 0 or screen_coords.x > screen_width or screen_coords.y > screen_height  then
        append theVerts v
)--end v loop
delete theMesh --release the memory used by the TriMesh
theVerts  --return the collected vertices
)--end fn verts in viewport

maksimum = 3
counter = 1
 while counter < maksimum do
 (
    move $Camera001 [0,-550,0] 
    cameraOK = getVertsInViewport $
    print (counter as string +"  "+ "camera_pos = "+ $Camera001.pos.y as   string +" : " +(cameraOK as string))
    counter += 1
 )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a call to forceCompleteRedraw() after moving the camera.

I assume you have the active viewport set to the camera view, since you're viewport.getTM() to obtain the camera transformation. The redraw seems to allow the viewport to refresh, respecting the new camera position, and give the intended result.

Note that MaxScript blocks the main thread of 3ds Max while running. That means UI events and other kinds of refresh activity are not processed, which is probably causing the conflict here.